# swift UITableView es posible dejar fijo el header de la tabla y el header de las secciones?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Tengo una tabla con un header y con varias secciones (cada una de ellas con header) y necesitaría que tanto el header de la tabla como los header de las secciones estén fijos... es eso posible usando un UITableView ?

A continuación les dejo el código de mi tabla:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        switch (section)
        {
        case 0:
            return 0
        case 1:
            return self.heigthHeader(results: self.transactions_PND)
        case 2:
            return self.heigthHeader(results: self.transactions_PAY)
        case 3:
            return self.heigthHeader(results: self.transactions_RJC)
        case 4:
            return self.heigthHeader(results: self.transactions_DUE)
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))

        let label : UILabel = UILabel()
        label.text = sectionTitles[section]
        label.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

        headerView.addSubview(label)

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        headerView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, topConstraint])

        return headerView
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch (section)
        {
        case 0:
           return 1
        case 1:
           return getNumberOfRows(results: self.transactions_PND)
        case 2:
           return getNumberOfRows(results: self.transactions_PAY)
        case 3:
           return getNumberOfRows(results: self.transactions_RJC)
        case 4:
            return getNumberOfRows(results: self.transactions_DUE)
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("QueryCollectTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! QueryCollectTableViewCell
         cell.selectionStyle = .none
        switch (indexPath.section)
        {
        case 0:
            cell.strLblPhone.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblTitlePhone",comment:"")
            cell.strLblPhone.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
            cell.strLblAmount.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblAmount",comment:"")
            cell.strLblAmount.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
            cell.strLblDate.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblDate",comment:"")
            cell.strLblDate.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
            cell.strLblReason.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblReason",comment:"")
            cell.strLblReason.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
            cell.addBottomBorder(Utils.Color.COLOR_C2922D, height: 2, separation: 0)
            return cell
        case 1:
            return getCell(cell: cell, resultTransactions :self.transactions_PND, row: indexPath.row)
        case 2:
            return getCell(cell: cell, resultTransactions :self.transactions_PAY, row: indexPath.row)
        case 3:
             return getCell(cell: cell, resultTransactions :self.transactions_RJC, row: indexPath.row)
        case 4:
            return getCell(cell: cell, resultTransactions :self.transactions_DUE, row: indexPath.row)
        default:
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Para popular cada una de las secciones manejo 4 listas diferentes. Las secciones no las debo mostrar en caso de no tener datos para mostrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pasa esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaria que el scroll lo tenga solo la lista... nose si esto es posible utilizando una unica UITableView.

Comment: Hola Tamara , para que te puedan ayudar trata de poner código formateado que llevas y ademas podrias poner alguna imagen para el resultado esperado o algo así. son detalles que ayudarán a que se encuentra una pronta solución. Saludos.

Comment: Intenta poniendo el header de la tabla directamente en la vista en lugar de header. y redimenciona tu tabla para que ésta quede debajo de la vista header

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Así quedo con la solución  de @jdev

[image]

Mi método quedo así para darle los estilos a los títulos de las secciones:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

```
    let label : UILabel = UILabel()
    label.text = sectionTitles[section]
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 5, width: 200, height: 30)
    label.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}
```

y el estilo de la tabla lo configure en el .xib de esta forma:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

La vista que tienes con `Celular`, `Monto`... en lugar de ponerla como `tableview.tableHeaderView`, tienes que ponerla fuera de la tabla. Es decir, en tu viewController, añades esa vista arriba del todo, y debajo añades el `UITableView`.

Después deberías settear el estilo de tu tabla a `plain`, de esta manera:

```
tableview.style = .plain
```

Y así tendrías las sticky headers, `Pendientes` y `Pagados` que se quedarían debajo de la vista de tabs que mencionábamos en el primer párrafo, mientras haces scroll.

Para que no se vean por debajo las celdas que suben, necesitas poner un `backgroundColor` a la vista del header. En tu método:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))
    headerView.backgroundColor = .white
    ...
}
```

Y con eso debería bastarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Con esto logre el resultado que esperaba!